# Azure Data Factory Mapping ADFv2

Tags: azure-data-factory

95% of my Mapping in the Copy Activity of ADFv2 is straight one to one mapping. However, I have a case where I need to map Source "MIDDLE_INIT" Column to the Sink Column in which the String must be
SUBSTR(PS_NAMES.MIDDLE_NAME,1,1). Can this be done in ADFv2 Copy Activity? (The government cloud doesn't have Data Flows so I have to use the Copy Activity).
Thanks
Mike

Comment: You could use the stored procedure target with a table type in the Copy activity and do this little transform in there.

Comment: Awewome both of you! So you are talking about Azure Table Storage and do the transforms there? I will google also to see if there are any examples of that. Thanks so much!! – Mike Kiser just now   Edit   Delete

Comment: No a stored procedure target would be used when the target is a SQL database of some sort.  What is the sink (target) for your Copy activity?

Comment: My Sink is Azure Blob Container with my file type as Json....(The Json comes from a REST API call...thanks!!

Comment: Ok well Copy task can’t do this.  You will either have to use the Copy task to land the data in your Blob Storage and then use something else to do the Transform, eg SQL, Databricks etc or use Mapping Data Flows.

Answer (score 1):

No, copy activity cant do this.

As wBob comments, you could copy data from your source to a table type and transform `SUBSTR(PS_NAMES.MIDDLE_NAME,1,1)` in stored procedure. Then use this table as source, copy to your sink.

Comment: Awewome both of you! So you are talking about Azure Table Storage and do the transforms there? I will google also to see if there are any examples of that. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have Azure SQL Database in your architecture, you can use it to shred JSON directly from your data lake, using its built-in abilities, namely `OPENROWSET` and `OPENJSON`.  Here is a simple example:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET (
    BULK 'raw/parliament/2020/09/25/members.json',
    DATA_SOURCE = 'somejsonstore',
    SINGLE_CLOB
) x
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON ( BulkColumn, '$.result.items' )
WITH (
    fullName            NVARCHAR(MAX)       '$.fullName._value',
    gender              NVARCHAR(100)       '$.gender._value',
    party               NVARCHAR(100)       '$.party._value'
)
```

Read more about OPENJSON [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/import-json-documents-into-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#import-json-documents-from-azure-blob-storage).

Here is another simple example shredding JSON which I imagine is similar to yours.  NB in this I create the JSON, but you'll need to import it using the above technique:

```
SET @json = '{
"PS_NAMES": {
    "FIRST_NAME": "w",
    "MIDDLE_NAME": "Susan",
    "LAST_NAME": "Bob"
    }
}'

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON ( @json, '$.PS_NAMES' )
WITH (
    FIRST_NAME          NVARCHAR(100)       '$.FIRST_NAME',
    MIDDLE_NAME         NVARCHAR(100)       '$.MIDDLE_NAME',
    LAST_NAME           NVARCHAR(100)       '$.LAST_NAME'
    )
)
SELECT 'original'AS [source], FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, LAST_NAME
FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT 'new', FIRST_NAME, LEFT( MIDDLE_NAME, 1 ) AS MIDDLE_INIT, LAST_NAME
FROM cte;
```

If you do not have an Azure SQL DB in your architecture, then write back with what you do have, eg do you have Databricks, ADLA, Azure Synapse workspace, Azure Functions, Logic Apps, something else?

Comment: Wow, very awesome Bob! We do have Azure SQL DB and I will read about shredding and use your example. Thanks so much!! Mike